# Does Joomla have some event which fires after auth?

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I'm using `plgAuthenticationMyAuthentication` plugin, which method `onUserAuthenticate` fires on authorization, but I'm wondering if there is some method which fires immediately after login before component load, that i could use `JFactory::getUser()`.

Comment: I think you can use onUserAfterLogin http://docs.joomla.org/J1.5:Plugin/Events/User

Comment: @JobinJose no such method...

Comment: Yes there is http://docs.joomla.org/Plugin/Events   maybe you are looking in the wrong place? But login happens well after authentication.

Comment: @Elin could you show some example?

Comment: I'm no sure what your question is but the whole authentication/authorisation/login set of activities is filled with events. You don't start the login process until after you are authenticated.

Answer (score 1):

There is, but you need a create separate user plugin which has the onUserLogin (disclaimer, from memory so name might be different) method you can hook into.  The below link should provide a good starting point

http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_profile_plugin